# Saving sprite sheet into separate images

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs5, sprite

I'd like to separate a 64px x 512px spritesheet into eight 64px 64px images:

[image]

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Divide on a large slice will cut it up into a grid of smaller regions (you can skip the naming step if you don't care about having nice names):

[image: Create slices]

Comment: Photoshop doesn't seem to like creating more than 100 slices per document. Also, I could only get Save for Web to export as gifs.

Comment: I have slice sheets with way more than 100 slices. Can you provide a sample document with an issue? You can set the file format for each slice (or all at once) in the Save For Web window — they can be PNG, JPEG, etc.

Comment: I have the same problem. First two are png and the rest are gif files.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open up the spritesheet in your image editor of choice.
2. Crop spritesheet down to the area you want.
3. Export new sprite.
4. Repeat until all the sprites you need have been exported out as individual images/sprites.

In Photoshop, use the web slices tool to "slice" up the sprites and then do a Save For Web. Make sure to export all the user slices. This will be much faster then the steps above.

Answer (score 0):

you can unpack the images from a sprite sheet using Spooky software , can unpack the .PNG sprite sheet image. alos you can merge it back

Check out below link :
http://store.bluegamerzstudio.com/downloads/spooky-spritesheet-extractor-and-merger/

Video Tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oRdrWrktL0M